# Using custom OpenIDConnect provider with AWS MobileHub

Tags: amazon-web-services, openid, aws-sdk, aws-mobilehub

I am building iOS app and was looking into AWS MobileHub...I am trying to setup sign-in using AWS Cognito, I have configured the identitypool with my custom OpenID Connect provider (I built my own with IdentityServer) but when I configure Sign in using the MobileHub it only gives me the option to use Facebook, Google, Twitter (coming soon), or a custom authentication backend (NOT OpenID)...am I missing something or is this not supported yet with MobileHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile Hub does not currently support OpenID Connect providers. However, because you have configured your Cognito identity pool to support OpenID, you can use the AWS SDK directly to handle authentication. This blog post should help:

https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3LP54JOGBE0AY/Building-an-App-using-Amazon-Cognito-and-an-OpenID-Connect-Identity-Provider